# distilled water and copper(II)chloride

Tags: experimental-chemistry

In class we did a lab of adding blue crystals of copper(II)chloride into distilled water, the water turned blueish green,were the changes chemical or physical?

Comment: Next time, you should write down your previous effort, what have you done and failed, to answer your question. If the question does not express your own effort, others may not be willing to answer, and may even vote for closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper%28II%29_chloride

> Aqueous solution prepared from copper(II) chloride contain a range of copper(II) complexes depending on concentration, temperature, and the presence of additional chloride ions. These species include blue color of $\ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^2+}$ and yellow or red color of the halide complexes of the formula $\ce{[CuCl_{2+x}]^{x−}}$

On the Wikipedia page, you can see a photo of 3 solutions with different colour.